# Can't assign delegate

Tags: ipad, memory-management, delegates

I have two view controllers. The flow between them is as follows:

VC1 creates VC2 and sets VC2.delegate to self. In VC2, the delegate property is assigned, not retained. When VC2 is displayed, VC1 is dealloced, thus the delegate property of VC2 is a zombie object. VC2 is supposed to retrieve some data from a server and call the delegate with that data, but that won't work since the delegate was already deallocated.

My question: should I just retain the delegate in VC2 and release it in the dealloc method of VC2, or am I missing something fundamental here since the delegate pattern in iPhone suggests assigning delegates and not retaining them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the delegate to nil before you dealloc VC1.
VC2 should not have any knowledge of VC1 (only what protocol it is conform to).

With retaining VC1 in VC2, VC1 will probably never get deallocated. (only with a really ugly structure of code)

It is obvious that when the object VC1 deallocated that is has to do its cleanup, so it has to set the delegate to nil.

Back to your question: you should never retain a delegate. Its just code construction.

Comment: But the delegate is VC1. Inside a method of VC1, I have VC2 vc2 = ...; vc2.delegate = self. Then VC2 is being displayed, and VC1 is being deallocated, thus the delegate property of VC2 is also deallocated. VC2 does not have any knowledge of VC1 indeed.

Comment: If you want VC2 to notify VC1, dont let VC1 be deallocated.

Comment: I can do that as per the first part of my question, but I was hoping that I don't have to retain the delegate in VC2 since it goes against the good practice of assigning delegates instead of retaining them.

Comment: With 'Dont let VC1 be deallocated' i do not mean retain it in VC2. VC2 is not the owner of the VC1 object. The object that allocated VC1 should not release it while it is still in use.

Comment: I agree. Will try to find a way to keep VC1.